# ReactJS autoformating while typing field and saving raw data at the sametime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

Good evening,

I want to make an autoformat field but I need to store the raw data and the formatted string and I want to auto format user's input in real time, while they are typing. I tried something like:

```
<input value={this.state.formattedValue} onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>

handleOnChange(e) {
   let value = e.target.value
   let formattedValue = this.formatValue(value) // my formatting function
   this.setState({formattedValue: formattedValue, value: e.target.value})
}
```

This will work for the first time but then `e.target.value` will be the formatted value plus the new user's input and I will lose the raw value.

Most of the example on internet take care of just one value (formattedValue) so it's easy but I need both raw and formatted value. I did in the past a version of this where the value was getting formatted on the blur event but in my current case I need it in realtime while typing. If I can get the last character typed by the user I will be able to concatenate it to the values in my state and manage the transformation + the raw value.

Thank you all

Comment: how do you want to format the input text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use two state properties, let's call them `rawInput` and `formattedInput`. `rawInput` will be an array and `formattedInput` will be a string. You can then get the last character of the input's value and push it to the `rawInput` array before applying your formatting rules to the value.

Here's an example (note, I'm using hooks and a functional component here, but you can follow the same principle using class based components):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
   const [rawInput, setRawInput] = useState([]);
   const [formattedInput, setFormattedInput] = useState("");

   const handleInput = e => {
       const val = e.target.value;
       const lastTypedChar = val[val.length - 1];
       setRawInput([...rawInput, lastTypedChar]]);

       const formatted = val.replace(/[A-Z]/g, c => c.toLowerCase()); // use your own format function here
       setFormattedInput(formatted);
   };

   return (
     <div className="App">
      <h1>Input</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} value={formattedInput} />
       <p>Raw Input: {rawInput.join("")}</p>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-dream-qrni6?file=/src/App.js) with a working example.

Note that you will need to apply more logic to handle when a user deletes characters or pastes strings with length greater than 1 into the input if you need that. But the principle of splitting the state is what is important here.

Comment: This fails when the user deletes their input. For example when user types "f", "o", "o", `rawInput` is `"foo"` but as soon as user clicks backspace the `rawInput` changes to `"fooo"` not `"fo"`

Comment: @HyunwoongKang Yes, I mentioned that in the post.

Comment: That won't work as I tried to explain in my post. Let's take the example of `(xxx) xxx-xxxx` (french canadian phone number format). For the beginning it's ok, but once you'll get to the closing `)` you'll have an issue since the e.target.value will be `(xxx)` and the last char is `)` so the raw value will be `xxx)` instead of `xxx` (same issue when you delete all the numbers at a certain point the last char will be `(` )

Comment: That's why I wan to know if there is a way to get the last typed char (the one that trigger the onchange event)

Comment: @NicolasOuldBouamama Last typed char is `val[val.length - 1]` as I've included in the call to `setRawInput`. I'll make an edit to make this more clear

Comment: Oops, sorry. I guess I figured it out and you're right. I'll try some stuff and then I'll let you know if what I get is right.